# Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon

Tags: mariadb

So this happened after a reboot

```
sudo systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since sam 2018-01-13 00:12:28 EST; 10min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3463 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

jan 13 00:11:57 miguel systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon...
jan 13 00:11:58 miguel mysql[3463]:  * Starting MariaDB database server mysqld
jan 13 00:12:28 miguel mysql[3463]:    ...fail!
jan 13 00:12:28 miguel systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
jan 13 00:12:28 miguel systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
jan 13 00:12:28 miguel systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
jan 13 00:12:28 miguel systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Please, ask your question in a clear way. Posting a systemd status output without further information will most likely bring no answer. Also, check the mysql logs and post any relevant part with your question.

Comment: Run `journalctl -xe` for more details about the errors.

Answer (score 3):

```
/etc/init.d/mysql: line 114: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: No such file or directory
```

Well for some reason mysqld_safe is missing. No idea where it went...

I simply apt-get remove --> install --> mysql_secure_installation and problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

To check for details about the error, run:

```
$ journalctl -xe
```

For more details about the error, check logs:

```
$ tail /var/log/mysqld.log
```

To initialize the MySQL configuration, run:

```
$ mysqld --initialize-insecure
```

Answer (score 0):

On my situation I was playing around around with the configuration file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and forgot that I changed the directive `bind-address  = 192.168.1.15` to a Dynamic IP, since the IP changed it could not listen to that IP anymore.

The solution on my situation was to switching back to the local IP `(127.0.0.1)` or setup the Static IP in your server.